# Updating a property when a different property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have some XAML

```
<Button Background="{Binding ButtonBackground}" />
<Label Background="{Binding LabelBackground}" />
```

that both should update on the same property changed event `IsRunning`
So far I have three properties, `ButtonBackground`, `LabelBackground` and `IsRunning` with `IsRunning` explicitly firing the `OnNotifyPropertyChanged` for all three. This is tedious and prone to bugs if I decide to add a new property that should update on the same trigger.

Is is possible to instruct the data binding to get the value of a property when a *different* property is changed? Maybe something like `<Button Background="{Binding ButtonBackground, Source=IsRunning} />`?

Comment: there are several ways to implement the pubsub pattern here!!, also, as far as I know knockoutxaml doesn't exit yet:)

Comment: If you notify with no parameter it will notify all.  I typically add a method NotitifyAll() so it is in one place.

Answer (score 1):

If your `IsRunning` property is a `DependencyProperty`, then you can just add a `PropertyChangedCallback` handler. This handler will be called every time that the `IsRunning` property is updated, so you can set your other properties from there:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsRunningProperty = DependencyProperty.
Register("IsRunning", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, 
OnIsRunningChanged));

public bool IsRunning
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsRunningProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsRunningProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnIsRunningChanged(DependencyObject d, 
DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    // Update your other properties here
}
```

If it's not a `DependencyProperty`, then you can just update your other properties from the setter:

```
public bool IsRunning
{
    get { return isRunning; }
    set
    {
        isRunning = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsRunning");
        // Update your other properties here
    }
}
```

Comment: So in other words, it is _not_ possible to bind the update trigger to another property updating?